# how to manage accelerometer value .x and .y

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

hello i am making game application in that game  i a moving game using accelerometer 
but i want that my ball should not move in upper direction , only move my ball in right ,left and bottom side

please  help me........

Comment: [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) by Jon Skeet will help you write better questions in the future, and better questions will help us help you. That is: you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of gravity to +ve or -ve.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the BubbleLevel sample code available at

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BubbleLevel/Introduction/Intro.html

This will help you for sure.